# How can I send keyboard shortcuts SHIFT+CTL+F using a QR code, & scanner

Tags: powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, integration, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am trying to use a QR code to fire up the search function in my CRM.

I understand that QR scanners emulate keyboard keystrokes and I need to load the Client Name into the search function of My CRM.

I have successfully done so with a power shell command (see below to search for incoming phone numbers). However, I'm looking to avoid any code. If I need code the next question is how to fire up a .exe file from a QR code ...

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$InString = $args[0]
$OutPattern = '## #### ### ###'
$AppPID = 1234
$AppNm = ""

$OutString = "{0:$OutPattern}" -f [int64]($InString.Trim('+'))

$AppPID = get-process "Light Blue*" | select -expand id
$AppNm = Get-Process appname | select -expand id


$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate($AppPID)

Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('+^f')
$wshell.SendKeys($OutString)
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
exit
```

I suspect it may be in the scanner settings in the way I need to **encode for the control modifiers.**

I have purchased this scanner https://www.dropbox.com/s/2m0umd48z80wwgc/TR-UM006-%28HW0002%2BHW0008%2B8100%29%20EN-2021.6.22-S01.pdf?dl=0

Connected to win10 PC via USB cable and it showed up as a keyboard USB composite device Barcode scanner.

all my QR attempts have resulted in plain text output `+^fTest Data~`

Please help ...

Comment: Tag this with powershell...

Comment: Thank you although is this really a Powershell issue?

Comment: It has less to do with the scanner, and more WScript.Shell#SendKeys.